# Assemble date object from integers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsinteger

Given three integers, representing a day, month and year, what code would assemble those integers into a date object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at `NSDateComponents`:

```
int y = 2011;
int m = 1;
int d = 15;


NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dc setYear:y];
[dc setMonth:m];
[dc setDay:d];

NSLog(@"%@: %@", [[dc date] class], [dc date]);
```

Comment: +1 for being correct in principle, but the implementation is wrong.  `NSDateComponents` does not have a `-date` method, though you can convert one into an `NSDate` using `NSCalendar`.

Comment: I double-checked `NSDateComponents` class documentation (iOS 4.2 docset) and I see `-date` method right between `calendar` and `day` methods. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I've checked the Mac OS X 10.6 docset and `NSDateComponents` does not have `-date` method indeed. The question has iOS tag, so I figured it's for Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) uses the [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for parsing date strings into dates. So, format your integers into a date string and then use and NSDateFormatter to parse it:

```
// assume year, month and day are integers that are formatted properly and don't
// include invalid ranges
NSString* dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d %02d %02d", year, month, day];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Choose a format of YEAR MONTH DATE per the standard
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd"];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
[formatter release];
```

You can set the format string to whatever format floats your boat, as long as you use the Unicode Standard (linked above) and you convert your integers into the same format (obviously).

Comment: You may want yyyy not YYYY... capital letters gets you the crazy ISO week calendar, iirc.

Comment: @Catfish_Man you're right, I meant the yyyy numbers not the ISO year-week numbers! Thanks!