# convert Integers to Date Objects VB

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 integers and 1 String. Now I want to convert it in date objects and display it in datepicker1 (I set its format to "*short*")

for example:

```
Dim Day As Integer = 14
Dim Month As String = "July"  
Dim Year As Integer = 2016
```

I am expecting an answer as

```
7/14/2016 'this must be displayed in datepicker1
```

I searched through the internet and i found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743903/assemble-date-object-from-integers) but this is from different language and i want it in VB. if my question has already been asked before. please post the link.

I am new to vb so i am hoping for your help guys!

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VBA - they are totally different...

Comment: try DateSerial Function in vb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way that uses [`Date.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim dt = Date.ParseExact($"{Year}-{month}-{day}", "yyyy-MMMM-dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Note that i'm using [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) at `$"..."` which is available in VS 2015/VB14. Otherwise you could use `String.Format`:

```
Dim dtStr = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", Year, month, day)
Dim dt = Date.ParseExact(dtStr, "yyyy-MMMM-dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find more informations about the custom date and time format strings.